# Free alternative to the Ozeki Webphone?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, voip

Currently I am using the trial version of the Ozeki Phone System XE, which comes with a nice Webphone to make calls through the browser.

I have got it all working, but I think I scared the customer a bit with the Ozeki pricing for their services. I was asked to find a possible free alternative (*of course*).

After a few days of research I found that Asterisk offers a free PBX server. Even though it has to be configured and be put on a dedicated Linux server (the Windows version found here is pretty much obsolete), it looks promising.

However, I can't seem to find a "simple" interface to create a webphone. I found that sip5ml looks like what I need, but since I am not a JS expert (and definitely not a Linux expert), I find it hard to understand how it all works and how it should be implemented in Asterisk.

Then there is 3CX. 3CX seems to offer the same PBX server as Asterisk (and even better, since it comes with a nice browser-based GUI and it's on Windows), but it doesn't offer the same simple Webphone as Ozeki does.

All I want to do is make a voice (and video, in the future) call through a browser. One of the restrictions is that I do not want my calls to be sent through an external server (like Phono.js does by sending calls through the Tropo server).

So, all in all, the question is:

Is there a free webphone available, preferably on Windows, which allows me to make voice- and videocalls through a browser, which doesn't route the calls through an external server and is easy to configure with an existing PBX server?

Comment: May be Asterisk or FreeSWITCH.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PortSIP PBX](https://www.portsip.com/portsip-pbx) with [PortSIP WebRTC Gateway](https://www.portsip.com/webrtc-gateway/) solution, it allows you make & receive audio/video call in browser.